# Can actor wakes up after passivation from publisher

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

Please, answer if a persistent actor is up and subscribes to a topic with PubSubMediator for the communication with counterparts and after some timeout the actor system passivates non-active this actor. Could this actor wakes up if he receives a message from publisher?

Answer (score 0):

Passivated actor always wakes up on first message so yes it will.